# Output is showing different

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   
int a[6]={2,5,4,6,1,3};
int j,key,i,k;   
for(j=1;j<6;++j)
{
    key=a[j];
    i=j-1;
    while((i>=0)&&(a[i]>key))
    {
        a[i+i]=a[i];
        i=i-1;
    }
    a[i+1]=key;
}

for(i=0;i<6;i++)
printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}
```

When I calculate myself I get 1,2,3,4,5,6 but the output is 2,4,5,6,1,3.

I tried so hard, but couldn't find what is wrong in this.

Comment: `a[i+i]` accesses the array out of bounds and invokes *undefined behavior* (also the entire logic of that `while` loop seems odd - what is it supposed to accomplish?)

Comment: Also: Asking people not to downvote your question usually has the opposite effect. And you haven't shown your debug efforts either

Comment: I'm not saying don't downvote please tell me the reason for it(i know people do even i do) , please explain this accessing the array out of bounds in detail

Comment: If `j = 5` (last iteration of the `for` loop) then what value do you think you are accessing in `a[i+i]`?

Comment: There's usually little gained in trying to explain undefined behaviour. Accept it as it is: undefined, and avoid it in the future, i.e. use indexes that are within the array bounds.

Comment: a[i+1]=a[5] if it doesn't go into while loop because in previous statement i =j-1

Comment: You have `a[i+i]` (i plus i). Do you see a difference between `a[i+i]` and `a[i+1]`?

Comment: You don't have "i plus one", but "i plus i". Change your font, if that is not clear.

Comment: @llja Everilä I started reading introduction to algorithms its the first algorithm in it I executed it showing like this, should I follow that book or leave it

Comment: The book is probably not to blame here.

Comment: If you had stepped through this with your debugger, noting the result at each stage, and comparing it with what you expect, you would have spotted the 'i+i' typo when the array element load that you expected did not happen.  If you cannot debug, you cannot write programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your program.

Instead of

```
a[i+i]=a[i];
```

there shall be

```
a[i+1]=a[i];
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Also it is a bad idea to use "raw numbers" throughout the program.

It is desirable to place the sorting into a separate function.

The corresponding program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insertion_sort(int *a, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        size_t j = i;
        int value = a[i];

        for (; j != 0 && value < a[j - 1]; --j)
        {
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
        }

        if (j != i) a[j] = value;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 2, 5, 4, 6, 1, 3 };
    const size_t N = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d ", a[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    insertion_sort(a, N);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d ", a[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2  5  4  6  1  3
1  2  3  4  5  6
```

For big arrays it is better to use the binary search instead of sequential comparisons.

Comment: @Charan2628 No problem.:)

Answer (score 1):

The error is on a[i+i]=a[i] line.It should be a[i+1].when you have i+i(and i>=3) it tries to access the index on which you don't know what is going on,because it's not a's space.

Answer (score 0):

Here your array size is 6, as you declared A[6]. Now consider the case i=4, so in this line `a[i+i]=a[i]` you are trying to access `a[4+4]=a[4]`.

You cannot access the index `a[8]`. Simply change `a[i+i]` to `a[i+1]` will solve the issue.